# What is the analogue to a (directed) path in graph theory called in the theory of relations?

Tags: relations, order-theory

*My level is undergrad-master with little or no formal knowledge of relation or order theory, but with some graph theory.*

Let $R$ be a binary relation on a finite set $X$. I was looking for terminology and notation for describing a set like

$P=\{(x_1,x_2),(x_2,x_3),(x_3,x_4),\dots,(x_{k-1},x_k)\}$,

i.e. in a sense a *directed path* if this was graph theory.

For orders I've heard of [*chains*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains) being sets of pairwise comparable elements. But, as I understand it this requires transitivity, e.g. $P$ above is not a chain. I thus see chain mostly (if not only) defined for partial orders, which makes sense.

I also found the definition of a [*fence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(mathematics)) in for example Schroeder's *Ordered Sets* (Def. 2.37). He mentions that they can be seen as analogues to paths in graph theory. However, they are paths with alternating orientation. I guess what I was after was an analogue of a directed path, that does not require transitivity.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a terminology and/or notation for sets like $P$ above purely for relations, akin to the one of *directed paths* in a graph? Preferably, I'd simply denote it as $x_1x_2x_3\dots x_{k-1}x_k$, and even concatenate elements and "paths" into new ones like $yPz$, similar to the notation used in e.g. Diestel's *Graph Theory*.
2. Would anyone recommend a good (preferably introductory) treatment on the correspondence between relations, orders and graphs?

*Most books for undergrads focus more on order and specifically partial orders. Books I found on more pure relations have either not explicitly contained such definitions, or have been a bit too advanced for me to notice. Also, the abundance of terms for the same things sometimes makes it hard to find what I want, e.g. chain, total order, linear order, simple order, connex order, etc. I looked in e.g. Steven Givant's *Relation Algebras*, but did not find any such notation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes "graph" is used to mean exactly the same thing as a binary relation on a set (a directed graph without multiple edges but where loops are permitted), but of course not always. It seems to make good sense to talk about a "path" in a relation, although "directed path" would be ok for emphasis. Maybe a "path" would be a directed path in the symmetric closure of the relation. While it is important to respect existing terminology, especially when talking to a specific audience, mathematics has a culture of generalizing the meaning of terms. If this is done thoughtfully, the freedom to do so is part of the creativity of the subject. Feel free to develop the terminology and probably writing the precise definitions will be an important part of learning. For example: it's not clear that the set $P$ is quite right in the question (what if the path contains cycles?); should it be a sequence not a set? is it the sequence of pairs in $X \times X$ or the sequence of elements of $X$ that matters most?

From a purely relational point of view (in the Relation Algebra setting of Givant's book you mention) the emphasis is more on the properties of $R$ as a whole, rather than the individual elements (we might call them arrows or pairs) in the relation. In fact, there are models of the relation algebra axioms that cannot be represented as concrete relations on a set (non-representable relation algebras).
Thus if your application needs to talk explicitly about the pairs in the relation there must be something involved that goes beyond the operations in a relation algebra.

Composition of $R$ with itself "forgets" the route used between the two endpoints and only measures the existence of a route. To get involved with different routes between the same endpoints, you might need to bring in category theory. See, for example, the wiring diagrams on p42 of Fong and Spivak *An Invitation to Applied Category Theory* (2019).

For other sources of information on relations, there is Gunther Schmidt's *Relational Mathematics* (2011) and possibly Schmidt and Strohlein *Relations and Graphs* (1993).

Comment: Good points! My thoughts are that it wouldn't matter what order I list the pairs of $P$, it still constitutes the same path. I mean informally, it's the directed edges that are listed: E.g. $\{(x,y),(y,z),(z,x)\}$ is the 3-cycle, and so is $xyzx$. However, in the latter case order matters of course, which is also implicit in the representation being a string. Yes, I noted that Givant's is about the algebra of relations and is thus about properties/relations of relations so to speak, rather than internal properties in a sense. This was just the simplest introduction to relations that I found.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I should have remembered that in a path the vertices are distinct, as opposed to a walk where it could matter.

Comment: Ok, well I think I'll develop the notation of paths for relations, allowing me to say things like $P$ above being a $x_1-- x_k$ path and so on. This is very useful for a few proofs and arguments I make in my thesis, and useful in general when speaking about the internal structure of a relation. I was just curious to see whether the were some accepted terminology that I missed (relation theory on its own can seem almost esoteric at times). As with my previous question that you answered, I will leave a little room for more answers before accepting.

Comment: If you'll excuse me for snooping, I will also look into your knowledge representation and reasoning project; I remember really enjoying reading about Ologs in _CT for the Sciences_ by Spivak a while ago. (Thank you!)

Comment: That's good. I got into relations by wondering "what is a relation on a graph?". Of course there are many answers to that, but category theory helped in places, and some of the work ended up here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jlamp.2015.11.003

Comment: Speculatively, I feel the question is connected with this: https://twitter.com/jcreed/status/1332448633543942146?s=20

Comment: Yes, that's very interesting. Am I mistaken, or would a relation on $G$ be something like a subobject of the product $G\times G$ in __Graph__ ? Or would one use Galois connections? I've just started reading about GC, so I don't feel that I've understood it yet.

Comment: That's one good answer. I wanted something that fitted the characterization of relations on a set as join-preserving functions on the lattice of subsets. This is where adjunctions come in. The lattice of subgraphs is not Boolean which is one reason it gets interesting. Maybe this should be a separate question - I certainly don't know all the options or if they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I guess we should try to keep this comment section free from further digressions. But, I will come back to this question some time later. If there's a way to get in touch here on stack (?), let me know if you get into such a discussion through a question here, otherwise I'll post a separate question about this in the future. (I'm sidetracked as it is from my thesis. I have just encountered so many interesting things while researching that I can't help my self: e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073076/is-there-a-general-notion-of-reduction-possibly-dual-to-that-of-closure )